# Webpack: How can I create a loader for "webpack" which takes an array of dependencies?

Tags: javascript, requirejs, webpack, amd, commonjs

For example, I use AMD definition in my project, and use "webpack" for project building. It's possible to create some loader which will take a dependencies in array format?

```
define(
    [
        'mySuperLoader![./path/dependency-1, ./path/dependency-2, ...]'
    ],
    function() {
        // ... some logic here
    }
)
```

Project example: [gitHub](https://github.com/dosandk/stackoverflow-questions/tree/master/35280020)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to port the `load`-plugin's behavior to webpack, you need to do this:

#### 1. Create a custom resolver

This is because `mySuperLoader![./path/dependency-1, ./path/dependency-2, ...]` does not point to a *single* file. When webpack tries to load a file, it first:

- resolves the file path
- loads the file content
- matches and resolves all loaders
- passes the file content to the loader chain

Since `[./path/dependency-1, ./path/dependency-2, ...]` is not a proper file path, there is some work to do. It is even not a proper JSON.

So, our first goal is to turn this into `mySuperLoader!some/random/file?["./path/dependency-1", "./path/dependency-2", ...]`. This is usually done by creating a custom resolver:

```
// webpack.config.js
var customResolverPlugin = {
    apply: function (resolver) {
        resolver.plugin("resolve", function (context, request) {
            const matchLoadRequest = /^\[(.+)]$/.exec(request.path);

            if (matchLoadRequest) {
                request.query = '?' + JSON.stringify(
                    matchLoadRequest[1]
                    .split(", ")
                );
                request.path = __filename;
            }
        });
    }
};

module.exports = {
    ...
    plugins: [
        {
            apply: function (compiler) {
                compiler.resolvers.normal.apply(customResolverPlugin);
            }
        }
    ]
};
```

Notice `request.path = __filename;`? We just need to give webpack an existing file so that it does not throw an error. We will generate all the content anyway. Probably not the most elegant solution, but it works.

#### 2. Create our own `load`-loader (yeah!)

```
// loadLoader.js
const path = require("path");

function loadLoader() {
    return JSON.parse(this.request.match(/\?(.+?)$/)[1])
        .map(module =>
            `exports['${path.basename(module, '.js')}'] = require('${module}');`
        )
        .join('\n');
}

module.exports = loadLoader;
```

This loader parses the request's query we have re-written with our custom resolver and creates a CommonJS module that looks like this

```
exports['dependency-1'] = require('path/to/dependency-1');
exports['dependency-2'] = require('path/to/dependency-2');
```

#### 3. Alias our own `load`-loader

```
// webpack.config.js

    ...
    resolveLoader: {
        alias: {
            load: require.resolve('./loadLoader.js')
        }
    },
```

#### 4. Configure `root`

Since `/path/to/dependency-1` is root-relative, we need to add the root to the webpack config

```
// webpack.config.js
resolve: {
    root: '/absolute/path/to/root' // usually just __dirname
},
```

---

This is neither a beautiful nor an ideal solution, but should work as a makeshift until you've ported your modules.

Comment: Thank you very much! Your answer is extra helpful!

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that you should use a loader for that. Why don't you just write:

```
require("./path/dependency-1");
require("./path/dependency-2");
require("./path/dependency-3");
```

It accomplishes the same thing, is much more expressive and requires no extra code/loader/hack/configuration.

If you're still not satisfied, you might be interested in [webpack contexts](http://webpack.github.io/docs/context.html) which allow you to require a bulk of files that match a given filter. So, if you write

```
require("./template/" + name + ".jade");
```

webpack includes all modules that could be accessed by this expression without accessing parent directories. It's basically the same like writing

```
require("./table.jade");
require("./table-row.jade");
require("./directory/folder.jade")
```

You can also create contexts manually like this

```
var myRequire = require.context(
    "./template",   // search inside this directory
    false,         // false excludes sub-directories
    /\.jade$/      // use this regex to filter files
);

var table = myRequire("./table.jade");
```

Comment: require("./path/dependency-1") - this is good approach, but I have a project that was wrote by using "requirejs" for module loading and "r.js" for building. I am trying to "soft" move project from r.js-building to build via webpack and I need the some wrapper around my requirejs loader-plugin.

Comment: So, are contexts an option for you?

Comment: Thank for your answer, I added [project example](https://github.com/dosandk/stackoverflow-questions/tree/master/35280020), maybe, this helps to find appropriate solution for me.